# known as, known to be and known for

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between the following sentences:

> 1 It's known as the most dangerous part of the city.

> 2 It's known to be the most dangerous part of the city.

> 3 It's known for being the most dangerous part of the city.

Answer (score 1):

"known as" is usually followed by an **alias / another name**. As such, this verb is not suitable in your context.

From [the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/known), the meaning of "known as" is:

> If someone or something is known as a particular name, that person or thing is called by that name:
> *And this is Terry, otherwise known as "Muscleman".*

---

"known for being" and "known to be" should be followed by a **characteristic**. As such, both are suitable in your context and there are no differences in their meanings.

Comment: can't "the most dangerous part"  be its name? like people actually calling it that?

Comment: If it's the name then it must be capitalised This makes for a very long name but I suppose it's theoretically possible, e.g. *"My address is, 21 Peril Street, The Most Dangerous Part, Gotham City, USA"* !!!  This does sound rather comical though. ;-)  -- (Pun intended)

Answer (score 1):

> 1 It's known as the most dangerous part of the city.
>
> 2 It's known to be the most dangerous part of the city.
>
> 3 It's known for being the most dangerous part of the city.

Yours is not a good set of examples for understanding the difference. I offer the following:

*Mr. John Johnson is known as Johnny (by his friends).

Mr. John Johnson is known to be grumpy.

Mr. John Johnson is known for his gardening skills.*

Answer (score 0):

> 1: *District X is known as the most dangerous part of the city*
> 2: *District X is known to be the most dangerous part of the city*
> (In this exact context, these two are more or less equivalent.)

Note that format #1 above is commonly used where what follows ***known as*** is in fact an *alternative name*, that might sometimes be enclosed in "scare quotes". We can't really interpret #1 as equivalent to *"**The most dangerous part of the city**" is an alternative name for District X*, but that interpretation would certainly work with ***District X is known as "Chinatown"*** (quotes optional).

There could also be some implication in #2 that establishing exactly which is the most dangerous area is a matter of some concern to the locals. They have therefore made significant efforts to establish that the answer is *definitely* "District X" (no-one doubts this fact).

> 3: *District X is known for being the most dangerous part of the city*
> This version asserts that (one of) the best-known characteristics of District X is the fact of it being the most dangerous area - often with the strong implication that *if it weren't so dangerous, most people wouldn't even know of the existence of District X.*